# PowerBI - Using an Azure blob as a DataFlow data source

Tags: azure, powerbi

Hopefully someone can help. I have a requirement of creating something like a "bring your own data model" feature/steps so clients can upload their own files, use it in a PowerBI data flow, link it with other sources (databases, services, etc), and create reports from it. The only problem is I'm having problems creating a data flow from an Azure blob file.

1. The files are CSV format
2. I have premium feature
3. I first tested and created an M query in PowerBI Desktop and it works, I can access the data

[image]

4. What I do is I copy my created M query to the Power BI data flow data source in a blank query. The result will is I can preview the data, but if I try to save it, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I tried the steps on this [link](https://radacad.com/workaround-for-computed-entity-in-power-bi-pro-dataflow-in-power-bi) but no luck.

Any ideas?